# Meaning of lonely in a particular context

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

My friend is_____ child. It must be boring not having brothers and sisters.

a. a lonely

b. an only

To me, both are correct. 
The context support both lonely and an only.

My friend is a lonely child. It must be boring not having brothers and sisters.

She is lonely because she hasn't got any siblings.

Lonely means unhappy because you are alone or do not have anyone to talk to.
So, the one who hasn't got any siblings can also be lonely, not only an only.

A lonely old man. ( when people usually leave)

Won't you be lonely as well as an only when you do not have siblings? 
Please tell me whether I can use BOTH or not.

Comment: Both (a) and (b) are grammatically correct. Whether an only child is lonely depends on the circumstances. So being an "only" does not necessarily mean being lonely.

Comment: As Clare commented, both are grammatically correct but context is about "an only child".

Comment: Please, could you explain more?

Comment: I still think that the context was enough for both words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have different meanings:

An [only child](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/only-child) is:

> - a child who has no brothers or sisters.

A [lonely](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lonely) child is:

> - unhappy because you are alone or because you have no friends

MacMillan Dictionary

An only child is not lonely by definition.